# Why are the distributed point objects not aligning to the normals of the faces?

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces

I'm following this cool [YouTube Burger Tutorial](https://youtu.be/pi4wA1L8Q6A?t=1259) but unfortunately the *Geometry Nodes* part is not applicable in the latest versions of Blender so I had to do some adjustments but I'm not sure why the distributed objects don't align to the normals of the faces. I think I need to use a *Capture Attribute* node but I'm at a loss on how I should use it in my setup.

[image]

They align though to the normals if I mute the *Random Value* node but then they all face towards the center.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't actually need to use `Align Euler to Vector` in this case, since you already have the *Rotation* socket available. *Rotation* there is the direction of the points *as aligned to the normals* of the faces they're distributed on, so you can link that directly. Not every node will give you that information though, in those cases you might need to capture or sample the face normals and use that to align your vectors.

I would do any extra random rotations on top of that with a separate `Rotate Instances` node:

[image]